# Can't make a network call from background notification after app force-quit and phone restart

Tags: ios, background, notifications, restart

I am using background notifications in my app. And I use it to make a small call to our server after each notification. Tested on iPhone 5/6 and iOS 11

In those cases I am able to call the server to mark my notification as received :

- the app is in foreground
- the app is in background
- I just reboot my device

But sometimes users kill the app and then I can not call my server, that is a normal behaviour of background notification.

BUT, from the documentation :

> However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user
>   has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app
>   or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app
>   automatically again.

Source : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

So if I am correct, if I force quit the app and then restart my device I should be able to make a network call again after phone restart.

This is my issue, it does not work. After a force quit of my app and a phone restart the notification is displayed on the screen of the phone but the network call is not done.

Do you have the same issue ? Do you know a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Your application has to be in the multitasking stack to make a call to server when notification is received. That is, application has to opened atleast once after the reboot to meet your expectation.

Comment: Thanks iOS but when I just restart my phone (not after a force quit) my app is able to call the server when a notification is received on the device, even if the app is not in multitasking stack since the device has just been rebooted.